# scroll to section(id #one) add active class class jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

here is my jQuery Code
and here is my web page url: https://ipconsultingfirm.com/home/

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
     if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= jQuery("#one").offset().top + jQuery("#one").height() || jQuery(window).scrollTop() < jQuery("#one").offset().top){
        jQuery('#one').removeClass('active');
      }
      else{
            jQuery('#one').addClass('active');
      }
                        
});
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i want to add a class "active" when i scroll on and particular section
i-e section id="one"
when we scroll the page to that section i want to add class "Active"